# Non-HTTPS websites don't work over Anker ethernet adapter since Catalina

Tags: usb, catalina, ethernet, http

I'm having a weird bug where my [Anker USB-C hub](https://www.anker.com/es/products/variant/premium-usbc-hub-with-ethernet-and-power-delivery/A8302041) is messing with the ethernet connection. I can only visit HTTPS sites and HTTP sites get redirected to a page saying:

```
Router Behind Router Detected
warningError: The Connection Monitor has detected a third party router connected to the 5268AC
```

I believe this has only started happening since I last updated (currently on 10.15.4). Here are a few things I've tried:

- Testing with another MacBook gave the same results
- Testing on a different network just didn't resolve HTTP sites (no redirect)
- Testing with a different branded adapter on the same network is fine

Is there some reason this adapter doesn't work anymore? Is it fixable? Thanks!

Comment: This definitely has my interest especially since you positively identified the issue with the Anker adapter by testing a different brand.  Did you try contacting Anker?  If so, what did they say?  +1

Comment: Nope, but there aren't any driver downloads listed for the hub on their site and I don't see an easy way to contact them besides a phone number that's not manned right now. Also, I didn't buy it myself and have no way of returning/exchanging it unfortunately.

Comment: I was just on their website looking for drivers or a manual. Couldn’t find any.  Out of curiosity, what IP do you get when using the Anker versus the other adapter and what’s the IP address space of the network you’re on, does it match?

Comment: Actually, I did find drivers and it only lists support up to 10.12 (High Sierra).  You’ve tagged the question Catalina so this may be the issue.

Comment: Yep, I just installed those drivers just in case it might work and it didn't change anything (and I got some warnings that the kexts weren't supported in the installation).

Comment: [Router behind router detected ... (5268AC)](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/85wmbv/router_behind_router_detected_and_cannot_update/)

Comment: This isn't an issue with the router because I get similar issues with the hub on other networks.